# I am trying to find an alternative since ChainedKafkaTransactionManager is showing @Deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

So this is my implementation of ChainedKafkaTransactionManager so this is managing both the kafkaTransactionManager and JpaTransactionManager sice ChainedKafkaTransactionManager is deprecated i want a alternative of it to achieve same functionality.

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DunningCycleKafkaConfiguration {

    private final KafkaConfigurationProperties kafkaConfigurationProperties;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, kafkaConfigurationProperties.getConsumer().getEnableAutoCommit());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConfigurationProperties.getConsumer().getGroupId());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, kafkaConfigurationProperties.getConsumer().getKeyDeserializer());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, kafkaConfigurationProperties.getConsumer().getValueDeserializer());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConfigurationProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, kafkaConfigurationProperties.getConsumer().getMaxPollRecords());
       
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            AfterRollbackProcessor<Object, Object> processor,
            ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> chainedKafkaTransactionManager) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setRecordInterceptor(new KafkaConsumerInterceptor());
        ContainerProperties containerProps = factory.getContainerProperties();
        containerProps.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.valueOf(kafkaConfigurationProperties.getListener().getAckMode()));
        factory.setAfterRollbackProcessor(processor);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedKafkaTransactionManager);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> chainedKafkaTransactionManager(
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager,
            KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaTransactionManager) {
        return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<>(kafkaTransactionManager, transactionManager);
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public KafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> kafkaTransactionManager(ProducerFactory<Object, Object> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public AfterRollbackProcessor<Object, Object> processor()
    {
        DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<Object, Object> processor = new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<>(
                new FixedBackOff(1000L, 3L));

        processor.addNotRetryableExceptions(DataIntegrityViolationException.class);
        processor.addNotRetryableExceptions(IllegalStateException.class);
        processor.addNotRetryableExceptions(RestClientException.class);
        processor.addNotRetryableExceptions(NullPointerException.class);
        processor.addNotRetryableExceptions(NumberFormatException.class);
        processor.addNotRetryableExceptions(IllegalArgumentException.class);
        processor.addNotRetryableExceptions(NoSuchMethodException.class);
        processor.addNotRetryableExceptions(JsonParseException.class);
        processor.addNotRetryableExceptions(MessageConversionException.class);
        return processor;
    }
}
```

I have tried with @Transactional approach but don't know if it is right way of doing it.

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    @Transactional
    public KafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> kafkaTransactionManager(ProducerFactory<Object, Object> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory);
    }

@Bean
    @Transactional
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
```

Comment: I recommend looking at the "Outbox Pattern" and using tools like Debezium to get data into Kafka or Kafka Connect to get data out of Kafka and into a database. Two-phase commits (2PC) / transactions can cause issues if Kafka and/or the database is down, while the other is available... In general Kafka can be more highly available than any database (with high replication factor topics), so the chances of its transactions failing are much lower than the database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `@Transactional` on the TM bean definitions; that is meaningless.

Just use `@Transactional` (with the JPA TM) on the listener method (and only inject the KTM into the container). That will be very similar to the CKTM - when the listener exits, the JPA transaction will commit, followed almost immediately by the Kafka transaction.

Similarly, if the listener throws an exception, both transactions will roll back.

Note that, as with the CKTM, this is best effort 1pc only, and it is possible that the JPA commit will succeed and Kafka transaction might roll back - so you need to deal with possible duplicates.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions